# Calculating the Limit of a Function that divisor approaches to zero

Tags: limits

I try to calculate the limit of a function:

$$ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2-3 , x \geq 0 \\ 3x, x < 0\end{cases}$$

Evaluate $ \lim_{x\to2} \frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}.$

A)$0\ \ \ \ $ B)$4\ \ \ \ $ C)$2\ \ \ \ $ D)$3\ \ \ \ $ E) No limit

---

My Deduction

$f(2) = 1$

When $x = 2,$ expression's divisor becomes zero, so I approach $2$ from negative and positive side.

Approaching from negative: ($\epsilon$ is very small positive value)

$x = 2 - \epsilon$

$$  \frac{4-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2 -1}{-\epsilon}   $$
$$  \frac{3-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2}{-\epsilon}   $$
negative infinity

Approaching from positive:

$x = 2 + \epsilon$

$$  \frac{4+2\epsilon+\epsilon^2 -1}{\epsilon}   $$

$$  \frac{3+2\epsilon+\epsilon^2}{\epsilon}   $$
positive infinity

Since approaching from negative and positive has different values, it has no limit, so answer should be E.

Key says B.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The shape of the problem has changed (after editing) .. Let me read it again.

Comment: Sorry, did I change something by accident?

Comment: My answer seems correct to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in the numerator, because $f(x) = x^2 - 3$ in this region, the numerator in both cases should be $((2 \pm \epsilon)^2 - 3) - 1 = (\epsilon^2 \pm 4\epsilon + 4) - 4 = \epsilon^2 \pm 4\epsilon.$

So in your left-handed limit you should have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\epsilon^2 - 4\epsilon}{-\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} -\epsilon + 4 = 4,$ and in your right-handed limit you should have $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{\epsilon^2 + 4\epsilon}{\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon + 4 = 4.$ Both one-sided limits go to $4,$ so the limit exists and is $4.$

Of course, as Lone Student points out, this is all a bit unnecessary, you can reach the same conclusion by factoring using the difference between two squares, or alternatively if you're allowed to use derivative rules then you can simply recognize this as $f'(2) = 2(2) = 4.$

Comment: Actually OP should accept your answer.  (+1)

Comment: I wonder the meaning of "OP"

Comment: Original Poster, I believe

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $\varepsilon$. Just use limit rules:

As you said $f(2)=1$. Then you can complete:

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2}(x+2)=4.$$

Comment: That is correct. Nevertheless he can use his epsilon approach and the question is where did he go wrong.

Comment: Even if you feel that the OP doesn't "need $\varepsilon$", what is needed at this level is a justification for each step in finding the limit.  The OP starts with a piecewise defined function, just to make things difficult.  Please edit.